# Ruby on Rails- How to scrape data which is loaded on page after scrolling down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get the title and price of all the products in the following link by scraping.
https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan

I am able to get the title and price of products but the problem is new products are added as we scroll down the page and URL of page is not changed.So I am not able to scrape info of products that are loaded after the page is scrolled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the ajax requests, that are called when new part of data is loaded.
They use pagination (`page=2`):

```
https://homeshopping.pk/categories/Mobile-Phones-Price-Pakistan?page=2&AjaxRequest=1&undefined
```

Just iterate throught pagination by incrementing `page` param.